# Obtain ALL children of a given node in TreeMap

Tags: java, parent-child, treemap

I am using java 8. I found out there is an object [TreeMap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treemap_class.htm) pre-implimented in java.
I am wondering how I can obtain children nodes of a certain node.

I have written the following recursive code, but it does not work.

```
static TreeMap<String,SimpleNode> tree = new TreeMap<String,SimpleNode>();

public Stack findChildrenToDelete(SimpleNode parentNode){
    Stack nodesToDelete = new Stack();
    nodesToDelete.add(parentNode.getId());
    SimpleNode children=tree.get(keyMaker(parentNode.getId(), parentNode.getType()));


        findChildrenToDelete(children.get(i));

     return  nodesToDelete;  
}
```

I mean **the method should provide a stack of children nodes**

I saw the methods of the class and i didn't find a straight forward solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by children nodes?

Comment: A tree node, can have some children true? In my case SimpleNode object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does *not* work is because you **don't do anything with the result of the recursive call**. You have to **append these children to the result**.

```
static TreeMap<String,ArrayList<SimpleNode>> tree = new TreeMap<String,ArrayList<SimpleNode>>();

public Stack findChildrenToDelete(SimpleNode parentNode){
    Stack nodesToDelete = new Stack();
    nodesToDelete.add(parentNode.getId());
    ArrayList<SimpleNode> children=tree.get(keyMaker(parentNode.getId(), parentNode.getType()));

    for(int i=0;i<children.size();i++){
        // add recursive children to the result
        nodesToDelete.addAll(findChildrenToDelete(children.get(i)));
    }
    return nodesToDelete;  
}
```

Alternatively you can pass a reference to the collection you are building and add to the collection during the recursion:

```
static TreeMap<String,ArrayList<SimpleNode>> tree = new TreeMap<String,ArrayList<SimpleNode>>();

public Stack findChildrenToDelete(SimpleNode parentNode){
    return findChildrenToDelete(parentNode,new Stack());
}
public Stack findChildrenToDelete(SimpleNode parentNode, Stack nodesToDelete){
    nodesToDelete.add(parentNode.getId());
    ArrayList<SimpleNode> children=tree.get(keyMaker(parentNode.getId(), parentNode.getType()));

    for(int i=0;i<children.size();i++){
        // pass a reference to the collection recursively
        findChildrenToDelete(children.get(i),nodesToDelete);
    }
    return nodesToDelete;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass the collection to the `findChldrenToDelete` as well. What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: @Salman: looks to me a better design would be that a `parentNode` has a list (for instance an `ArrayList`) that holds the children. Furthermore it is better to use generics for the collections.

Comment: @Salman: because you call `nodesToDelete.add(parentNode.getId());`. You can change these lines to `nodesToDelete.add(parentNode);` to add the node itself.